# Bash while loop that reads file line by line

Tags: bash, file-io, while-loop

There are two ways of reading a file line by line that I want to discuss here:

```
#!/bin/bash    

while read line    
do    
    echo-e "$ line \ n"    
done <file.txt
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash    
exec 3<file.txt

while read line    
do    
    echo-e "$ line \ n"    
done
```

So first version works fine but I don't understand the mechanism of working while loop with the file. But the mechanism of the second version I understand. But here I don't understand why it hangs and does not print anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first loop works because the redirection after the `done` applies to the whole loop, so the `read` there is reading from the file, not from the standard input of the script.

The second version hangs because `read` reads from file descriptor 0, which is standard input, and you've not typed anything there.  The `exec` line redirects file descriptor 3 for reading from the file, but you're not reading from file descriptor 3.

You could rescue the second by using:

```
exec <file.txt
```

Now standard input is read from the named file.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
exec 3<file.txt

while read -u3 line
do
    echo -e "$line \n"
done
```

`-u3` reads from file descriptor 3

Strange that `echo` does not have the complement switch like ksh's `print` command.

Answer (score 3):

There are few mistakes in your scripts.

1. Space between `$` and variable name. (may be bad edit)
2. Space between `echo` and `-e`. (may be bad edit)
3. Mentioning the read at a file descriptor where the file is open. You are reading the file at descriptor 0 and exec is running at descriptor 3.

It should be something like this -

```
#!/bin/bash    
exec 3<file.txt

while read line  
do
    echo -e "$line \n"
done <&3
```

Comment: Does `<&3` on the `read` line work?  It used to be the case, back in the bad old days of the real Bourne shell, that the redirection would be done each time round the loop, so you got funny effects (like the file being closed on each iteration).  I can well believe it has been modified since then so that things work a little more sanely.  *FWIW*: when I tried `bash` on MacOS X, with: `while read line < somefile; do echo $line; done`, I got the first line of `somefile` echoed repeatedly...but with the `<&3` notation, I did get the successive lines of the file.  Be **careful**!

Comment: Thanks Jon, I tried with the above script, it worked on my mac. http://cl.ly/ClDf but thats some useful info. Ill remember it. I am still very much new to bash. Have just been learning `awk` and `sed`. But will start some books on bash basics. :)

Comment: Have edited the answer to have `<&3` after `done` statement instead of `read` statement.

Comment: This works fine on Mac OS/X, don't forget the quotes: while read line; do echo $line; done <"somefile"

Answer (score 0):

-u3 is great for my purpose (reading only the following line)

```
#!/bin/bash

logs=(*Logs.txt)
[[ -e "${logs[0]}" ]] || exit 0

exec 3<"${logs[0]}"

while read -u3 line
do
        if [[ $(echo "$line"| grep -c SCSI_STATUS_CHECK_CONDITION) -eq 1 ]]; then
                read -u3 line
                echo "$line"
        fi
done
```